# Selenium Python - Nothing happens after click on element

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am new to selenium and I try to navigate on a page and to click on a button to get to the next page with selenium web driver.

This is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]')))
    
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print('Element found')
```

In addition to `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` I also tried `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` and `click()`. In all cases the statement "Element found" is printed to the console, but nothing happens on the webpage.
Here is the HTML bit of the button:

```
<span class="ACME-src-ACME-ui-Pagination--arrowRight">
<i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></I>
</span>
```

Every help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried clicking with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**Wait!! Looks like The Xpath you are using is incorrect.** Spans are not clickable objects. Or like they are clickable but do not do anything, which is exactly happening here. May be the "i" tag is something which should take click(However I cannot see any object in Dom taking click and performing a job)

***First provide me with the proper DOM.***

You can further try two more ways of doing it:-

```
button = find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/i')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**OR**

```
button = find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/i')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The ActionChain guided me to the answer as it threw out a "movetargetoutofboundsexception". I scrolled down and now the <span> element is clickable with a simple .click().